# compare two int array in j2me?

Tags: arrays, java-me, compare

In my app I have 2 images with same dimensions,that I would to give their RGB data and compare them.In j2me we can not use **java.util.Arrays** and so `Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` method. One way to compare them is using **for** loop and compare each element of two int array,but  i'm looking for better way.When I search in web I found ArrayUtils class,[here](http://btw.sourceforge.net/j2me-commons/apidocs/net/sf/btw/commons/ArrayUtils.html),that has some equals() methods,but it's method compare two arrays of objects and before compare int arrays convert them to  Enumeration by arrayToEnumeration(Object array) that creates an enumeration from given object.
Finally this is my question:
**Is there a better way to compare two int arrays in j2me?**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. From the Util class

```
    public static boolean equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: :Thank you for your time, I did it, but as I notice in the problem I'm trying to find a better way than "for".

Answer (score 0):

```
private int compareArray(String[] _array1, String[] _array2){

Vector m_length1 = new Vector();
Vector m_length2 = new Vector();

if(_array1 && _array2!=null)
{
for(int i=0; i<_array1.length; i++){
if(m_length1[i]!=null){
m_length1.add(_array1[i]);
}
}
for(int j=0; j<_array2.length; j++){
if(m_length2[j]!=null){
m_length2.add(_array2[j]);
}
}
}
if(m_length1.size()==m_length2.size()){
return 0; /*matching*/
}else{
return -1; /*no matching*/
}
}
```

You can modify it as int array or you can compare byte of each value.
For instance;

```
byte sample[] = {0,0,0,0};
sample= yourValue.getBytes();
```

Comment: :Thank you for your time, I did it, but as I notice in the problem I'm trying to find a better way than "for".

Comment: Instead of for, you can use iterator to check both vector.

Answer (score 0):

Convert byte array to String:

```
 public boolean equals(byte[] b1, byte[] b2){
     String strB1 = new String(b1);
     String strB2 = new String(b2);
     if(strB1.equals(strB2)){
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
 }
```